# Representing and adding negative numbers in Easy68k Assembly

Tags: addition, negative-number, easy68k

I'm trying to write a simple program in Easy68k that stores to negative values, adds them together, and then outputs them in the console. I am having trouble figuring out how to represent the negative numbers. We are asked that they be in hex format and output in decimal. Everything seems correct but the values themselves. I used 2s complement and then converted the two numbers to hex.

First decimal number = -102
Second decimal number = -87

Using 2s complement I converted the two numbers to hex (though I'm not sure if this is even correct):
-102 -> 1A
-87  -> 29

Here's my code so far:

```
addr EQU $7CE0
data1 EQU $1A
data2 EQU $29

    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

* Put program code here

    MOVE #data2,D1
    MOVEA.W #addr,A0
    ADD #data1,D1
    MOVE D1,(A0)

    MOVE.B #3,D0
    TRAP #15

* Variables and Strings



* Put variables and constants here

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

I even tried to just convert binary versions of the negative numbers straight to hex:

-102 -> 11100110 -> E6

-87  -> 11010111 -> D7

Which didn't work either. I also tried storing the binary version and adding them, but got the same result.

Here's the question:

Write a program in assembly to add the two numbers (-102 and -87). Inputs should be in hexadecimal format. Store the result in hexadecimal at an address $7CE0.  Print out the result in decimal.(Hint: use the track function task #3). If an error happens, you should also print out the error message as well.

I know I am misrepresenting the two negative numbers, but I just can't figure out how to do it right. I've looked everywhere and found nothing on how to store/add/output negative numbers in 68k. Any help is appreciated, this is for an assignment so I'm not expecting direct answers. Thanks!

Comment: How many bits are your numbers? For 16 bit values, I get 0xFF9A for -102 and 0xFFA9 for -87.

Comment: That wasn't specified in the question, so I wouldn't know. I added the question in the description.